# How I create bmp files (bitmaps) of a single color using delphi

Tags: delphi, bmp

I need a fast way to create 24 bits bitmaps (and save to a file) in runtime,specifing the Width , Height  and color

something like

```
procedure CreateBMP(Width,Height:Word;Color:TColor;AFile: string);
```

and call like this

```
CreateBMP(100,100,ClRed,'Red.bmp');
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can use the `Canvas` property of the [`TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TBitmap), setting the `Brush` to the color which you want to use, then call [`FillRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.TCanvas.FillRect) function to fill the Bitmap.

try something like this :

```
procedure CreateBitmapSolidColor(Width,Height:Word;Color:TColor;const FileName : TFileName);
var
 bmp : TBitmap;
begin
 bmp := TBitmap.Create;
 try
   bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
   bmp.Width := Width;
   bmp.Height := Height;
   bmp.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
   bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));
   bmp.SaveToFile(FileName);
 finally
   bmp.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Just what I was going to suggest. I've used this technique to have an owner draw combo box with colour names and a small image.

Comment: `bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Height, Width));`

should be

`bmp.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0,0,Width, Height));`

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to call FillRect. If you set the Brush.Color before setting the width and height the bitmap will use this color for all the pixels. I've never actually seen this behavior documented so it may change in future versions.